# How to provide hbase-site.xml to Flink streming job in yarn cluster mode

Tags: hbase, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have written a Flink streaming job that writes to HBase. I have been able to deploy it with Yarn cluster mode by providing the hbase-site.xml in the fat jar in resources folder. I want to be able to provide the path to hbase-site while deploying the job from master node.

I tried doing this with the "-yt" option but it didn't work. What is the correct way of providing an external hbase-site.xml file to a flink job.

Comment: Were you able to find anything for this? I'm also stuck on this with Beam Flink runner.